# XCode will not bind nib and source header file with control click

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, nib

I added a custom view controller class with interface (.h), implementation (.m) files, and UI (.xib) to an existing project.

When I ctrl-click and drag between the nib and the interface, it will **not** place an outlet or IBAction when I drag, so I can't link a UI element to a property.  Also, XCode does not bring up the corresponding interface file when I view the nib in assistant editor mode.

Note: I changed the name of the custom class.  I changed the filename and the references to it in the source.

Comment: After changing the name, does the File's Owner object in the nib point to the right class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you click on file's owner on the left and then in the identity inspector on the right, put in the custom class. You should then be able to make connections.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  My hack way of accomplishing this was to open the .xib file with a text editor and search for references to the old class name and change them.

Comment: Haha, good to know. Glad to help! Wouldn't mind an upvote as well!